# Accidentally made an alias for a pre-existing command on OS X

Tags: command-line, bash, unix, shell, alias

I was toying around with aliases and made an alias to take me to the directory where I store all my bash projects via the `cd` command.

However, I used 'bash' as a name for the alias. Now when I run all my bash projects with `bash "insertname".sh` it doesn't run, rather it gives me a `cd:` error message.

Realising my mistake, I deleted the alias but I still can't run my scripts.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Side note: instead of `bash "insertname".sh`, it's almost always better to make the script executable, use proper shebang and call `./insertname.sh`. Then you should rename it to `insertname` and call it as  `./insertname`. This way in case you port the script to Python or whatever, the `.sh` part of the name won't be misleading. The interpreter should not be reflected in the name.

Comment: I hate to laugh at your misfortune but this did make me chuckle... I've had my own share of mindless self-destruct moments on linux :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command `unalias` + the name of the alias to remove any aliases attached to the name. In my case I wanted to remove an alias attached to the command bash.

So I executed the following command: `unalias bash`.

If there is a lesson to be learned from this, it is to **always** make sure the alias you are making is not a pre-existing command.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip aliases by preceding a command with a backslash. You can also do the same thing if you use the full path to the command. Demo:

```
$ date
Wed Jun  1 17:23:01 PDT 2022
$ alias date='echo Nope'
$ date
Nope
$ \date
Wed Jun  1 17:23:08 PDT 2022
$ /bin/date
Wed Jun  1 17:23:10 PDT 2022
```